# Windows Server 2012 connecting remotely physical server fails but hyperv running on it is available

Tags: windows-server-2012, hyper-v, rdp

The scenario is as following. There is an Windows Server 2012 running on which an Hyper-V server is running. And users are able to RDP (remote desktop) to the virtual (Hyper-V) server. So normally I can RDP from HQ both the physical and virtual (Hyper-V).

The problem started after the users started getting the storage is full message when trying to connect the Virtual server 192.168.26.1. I tried to RDP the physical server 192.168.26.99 but it keeps failing. But strangely enough pinging works for both of them...

So I then tried RDP the virtual one and what gives.. It connects! BUT I now get an error saying access denied (the credentials are correct, with wrong ones I can't even connect to it).

I also let the users on remote reboot the server, it stays the same... Only option is to go there and fix it locally I guess..

But anyway, how is this possible? 
Did someone else also have something like this?